# upnp and port forwarding, how it works

Tags: router, port-forwarding, upnp

I know that some programs like utorrent use upnp to add port forwarding automatically, how ever port forwarding does not appear in routers setting?
I'm wondering how router pass traffic in/out without port forwardings have defined in admin ui.